# Implementing addition and multiplication of an ArrayList in Java similar to x+=[i]*i in Python

Tags: java, python, arraylist

I am trying to implement the following piece of Python code in Java using ArrayList. But it turns out to be a lot more complicated in Java than in Python. I feel like my code should work the same I don't really see why my Java code isn't equivalent.

```py
test=10
x=[0, 0]
i=0
while len(x)<test:
    #print([i]*i)
    x+=[i]*i
    #print(x)
    i+=1
```

With expected output:

```
[0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 2, 2]
[0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
[0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

My Java code to implement the code written in Python above:

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: In the Python code you're adding `i` elements to your list each iteration of the while-loop. In the Java code you're adding one element to the list each iteration. Different.

Comment: Also you calculate `number1` each turn through the while-loop and then don't use it for anything. I don't know what you thought that was doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the multiplication, as that's short-hand in python for copying.
Here is a naive implementation in java:

```java
int test=10;
ArrayList<Integer> ar1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ar1.add(0);
ar1.add(0);

int i = 0;
while ( ar1.size() < test)
{
    // implement x+=[i]*i in Java
    int number1 = i;
    for (int j = 0; j < number1; j++)
    {
        ar1.add(i);
    }
    i = i + 1;
    System.out.println(ar1);
}
```

Comment: If I ar1.add(i); twice I get the right output but I'm not  sure why tho.